# Get instance of a Symfony2 class executed by an event

Tags: symfony

I'm running some code by using an event listener:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{

    public $value;

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        $this->value = 1;   

    }

}
```

I need to be able to access the class properties (just $value in my example) on these two occasions:

(a) In a normal controller executed from a route.

(b) From a Twig template (using the Twig render command). I don't want to pass anything in to Twig to do this as it's actioned on every request.

...how would I do this? I suppose I need to get the object's instance, but considering it was the event that created it, I can't see how.

Comment: Do you really need to use a listener or a service would be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attributes` field of the `Request` class is usually used for populating stuff to be used by other parts of the code. For example, one of the Symfony listeners sets the `_route` parameter in it.

You can get the request from the `$event` object:

```php
$request = $event->getRequest();
$request->attributes->set('value', 1);
```

Then you would get it from a controller:

```php
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->attributes->get('value');

    // shorter but a bit less effective
    $value = $request->get('value');
}
```

And in Twig:

```php
{{ app.request.attributes.get('value') }}
```

Or shorter but a bit less effective:

```php
{{ app.request.get('value') }}
```

P.S. It would actually be more effective if you asked *what* you're trying to solve instead of *how*. You might be coming up with a complicated nonidiomatic solution to a problem with a simple and common idiomatic solution.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a good way. I'm really just trying to achieve the example I posted, but it would perform a little bit more processing and set a few more variables. The code runs on every request, sets some values from the config file, performs a few actions, e.g. reads the user agent and decides the type of device using etc. I think I will do all that and set those values in the Request object as you say. Does that seem a good idea?

Comment: Except for setting some values from the config file, it's okay to set those on the request object if you need to base decisions in controllers based on those values. You can get values from the config file in more idiomatic ways.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better way to do this? Like I say I want to perform some actions on every request and make variables from those actions available everywhere else. I'm currently thinking an event listener and setting the variables to the Request object, but if there's a better way I'd look at that. Thanks again.